# Redirect without locale in URL nextjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redirect, next.js, i18next

When I redirect in this way:

```
{
        source: "/restauracja",
        destination: "/restaurant",
        permanent: true,
      },
```

it redirect me to /pl/restaurant

How can I fix it and redirect without second 'pl'? It only happens with redirecting, normaly default local don't show itself in url. And this is a problem for SEO, as it duplicates sites. I would like to do global setting of 301 redirects from domain.pl/pl/* to domain.pl/*, but don't know how to do it and I couldn't fins solution by searching.

How it looks in next.config.js:

```
...
i18n: {
    // These are all the locales you want to support in
    // your application
    locales: ["pl", "en", "de"],
    localeDetection: false,
    // This is the default locale you want to be used when visiting
    // a non-locale prefixed path e.g. `/hello`
    defaultLocale: "pl",
    // This is a list of locale domains and the default locale they
    // should handle (these are only required when setting up domain routing)
  },
  async redirects() {
    return [
      {
        source: "/restauracja",
        destination: "/restaurant",
        permanent: true,
      },
      {
        source: "/klub-pub",
        destination: "/club",
        permanent: true,
      },
      {
        source: "/kawiarnia",
        destination: "/cafe",
        permanent: true,
      }
    ];
  },
});
```

thank you for helping

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that localized paths (like `restauracja` as the translated page of `restaurant`) are simply **not possible** with the [NextJs built-in i18n system](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/i18n-routing).

Here a list of what is possible and what not (apparently):

```
--- path --------- language -- possible -- remark ------------
/pl/restauracja  |    PL    |    no    | (translated path with locale, )
/restauracja     |    PL    |    no    | (translated path without locale)
/pl/restaurant   |    PL    |    yes   | (default path with locale)
/restaurant      |    EN    |    yes   | (default path without locale)
/en/restaurant   |    EN    |    yes   | (default path with locale)
```

I couldn't find any reliable information on this (neither how to do it nor a remark like "localized paths are not supported"), but everything I found looks like it is not supported.

I disabled the built-in i18n system completely, and implemented the whole thing myself.

Comment: Hey, thank you for answering.

The thing is, before we used link "restauracja", but now I want to redirect it to 'restaurant' as we don't use 'restauracja' any more. But doesn't matter which link I redirect, which doesn't exist anymore it always start with double 'pl', and I would like them to start like rest of the defoult pages - without second 'pl'.

Comment: look on our page: https://gopos.pl - all subpage are like https://gopos.pl/restaurant, https://gopos.pl/gohub and so on. If i change for another language like EN - https://gopos.pl/en/restaurant. But why when I redirect for example from 'restaurant' it redirect with double 'pl' - https://gopos.pl/pl/restaurant if 'pl' is a defoult language. I try to find solution for it, to fix it, as right now it has bad affect for SEO. 

maybe you can set up global 301 redirects from gopos.pl/pl/* to gopos.pl/* when I redirect?

Comment: Oh, ok, I totally misunderstood you. Can you try [locale: false](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next.config.js/rewrites#rewrites-with-i18n-support) ?  
Note that maybe adding a sitemap.xml and/or "canonical links" might be the more straight SEO approach. But that's a whole new complicated story.

Comment: I think the extra '/pl/' is kind of the "correct" localized url, without '/pl/' is the alias. Note that all your other default pages will also work with the '/pl/', alternatively.